# How to run a report by default in excel in code?

Tags: rdlc, dynamics-nav

I have tried

```
ChosenOutputMethod := CustomLayoutReporting.GetExcelOption;
```

on the report but when I press preview, it doesn't export to excel. I want to achieve so that every time when run, the report is exported in excel document.
I want it to be in the report itself as of report 116 customer statement.

I don't want to use SAVEASEXCEL function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's possible only using SAVEASEXCEL. Any reason why you don't want to use it?
You can also use the Excel Buffer to create reports in Excel directly.

Cheers

Comment: I want a report to export to excel by default because they are going to save their invoices. I will need to redesign the layout with excel buffer. If I use SAVEASEXCEL, I will need a report wrapper which will run the sales invoice. right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to press Print -> Microsoft Excel button.